# C++ Multiple Subclasses with same Variables

Tags: c++, class, state

I'm still pretty new to C++ (started this semester), and am currently designing a program that uses everything we have learned so far. I decided to base it around freight sorting, and the financial aspects of that, since that is also my job outside of uni.

The issue I'm having is that my current design has three subclasses with the exact same states/behaviours inside of them (reasoning below), and the lecturer is saying that isn't what they want, as it doesn't show the use of polymorphism; I do have another hierarchy dealing with employee objects that does though.

The idea behind the similar subclasses (satchel/carton/pallet) is that they are for different sizes of freight, and will thus have a different dollar per kilo value calculated for them at the time of construction. Due to this, they will each have different dimensional limitations placed upon them. A basic runtime view of this part of the code is as follows:

- Run program.
- Recursive function called that asks user if they want to add freight.
- If yes, function asks for L/W/H and weight measurements, as well as
  address etc.
- Function then calls either satchel, carton or pallet constructor
  depending on the given measurements. (i.e. if the weight is over 40kg
  it calls pallet regardless of the other measurements).
- Keeps asking user if they want more freight. Cycle repeats if yes.
- If no it asks about other stuff.

My question is hopefully quite simple. Are there any functional problems that can/will be caused by having the subclasses using the same states/behaviours?

I realise I could have them all as one class, and then have the price calculated later on, but I was under the impression that this would take longer to do as it would require checking over every freight object created.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A stripped down version of what you are currently doing *in code* will speak far more than a text description, as it stands I'm having trouble understanding the question.

Comment: I haven't actually started coding it yet as they're expecting a software plan to be marked off before we begin. I can go into more details if that's going to help, I just didn't want to write a book in the OP.

Comment: Can you at least give an example of the class hierarchy and interface?

Comment: It sounds as if you're confusing the idea of _class_ with that of _object_ (instance of class) and possibly the data that an object contains (usually object specific), with the object behavior (usually class specific) I'd suggest you create a solid object model for your application first and then work on how to implement that in C++.

Comment: The freight hierarchy is built as follows:

Superclass: Freight.
States: length, width, height, weight, address, cost
Behaviours: getters for the above values

Subclasses of Freight.
Class: Satchel
Class: Carton
Class: Pallet

All three subclasses look the same at face value, the only real difference is that they each have a different pricing index assigned to them to calculate the cost (i.e. a 5kg small satchel should cost less than a large 5kg box).

My intention was for the function to construct the relevant class based on the given dimensions, and to calculate the cost at the same time.

Comment: I'm not too sure about the confusion. I know that all objects within a class have the same states/behaviours, but the values of the states can be different (which is the point). I just don't know if going at it in the way I mentioned above is going to cause conflicts or not. It seems like it should be fine but I didn't want to spend all that time only to scrap it because it doesn't work.

Comment: Not calculating the cost while performing the input is exactly what is expected (input - process - output; a very standard factoring). You don't need to worry about the time it takes. Outputting the sum takes thousands of times longer than computing it by going through all the objects.

Comment: So in that case it would be simpler to just scrap the subclasses and just create freight objects, store them in an array (which is part of the grading system) and then loop over to calculate the cost later on? Wouldn't I then have to get the dimensions for each object and use a bunch of if statements to determine which category (satchel/carton/pallet) it falls under in order to price it?

Comment: Firstly, like @molbdnilo said, you don't really need to worry about performance. However, I too do not think that this is an appropriate use of inheritance or polymorphism. The three classes your instructor wants you to create, i.e. satchel/carton/pallet seem to exhibit the exact same 'behaviour'. If that is the case, you can just have the cost per kilo as a member variable that you initialize using a constructor argument of a single class 'FreightObject', and calculate cost on the basis of that.

Comment: Would there be a way to have different costs per kilo depending on the cubic dimensions within a single class? That's the only problem I can see with scrapping the subclasses. I could probably do it with a bunch of conditionals, but my current design was setting cost = weight*somevalue within the subclass constructors.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/H0zGU9H7        This is the kind of thing I was working with, keep in mind it's only a rough draft so far.

Comment: Sure, you can do it like this: http://pastebin.com/1jhr9CSv or on the basis of volume: http://pastebin.com/5P3UQcMN

Comment: Oh wow those are a huge help, thanks. I've never seen enum before, but I'm guessing that bit is some kind of flag used to affix the relevant pricing to the object?

Comment: I think I am going to just let you lookup what enums are. :) But yes, they serve to identify the freight object subtype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any functional problems that can/will be caused by having the subclasses using the same states/behaviours?

If you implement the same functionality multiple times, it might become very hard to maintain when your codebase grows. Over time, somebody will introduce an error by changing only one of the three calculation. It's pretty much a case of "[Do not repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)".

Your lecturer is right: your [code](http://pastebin.com/H0zGU9H7) does not use polymorphism. For practicing the use of polymorphism, I would expect an abstract base class among the line of:

```
class freight {
public:

  freight(const std::string& address, float weight)
    : address_(address)
    , weight_(weight)
  {}

  // do not forget the virtual dtor for polymorphic classes
  virtual ~freight() {}

  // subclasses might add more weight to the content
  virtual float weight() { return weight_; );

  virtual float cost()
  {
    return weight()*costPerKg();
  }

  virtual float costPerKg() = 0;
  virtual float length() = 0;
  virtual float height() = 0;
  virtual float width() = 0;

protected:
  std::string address_;
  float weight_;
}
```

In a more complex system, you might even want to separate the interface from the base implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had a feeling the biggest issue was managing the system as it gets larger. I'm aware that the code I linked doesn't use polymorphism, the idea was just to get different cost calculations to work within one class, which was explained in the comments on the OP.